# Uniformly $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

This is sort of a reference request. I recall that there was a notation for functions that are $L^2$ on intervals $[n,n+1]$ for example and´these $L^2-$norms are uniformly bounded. It was something like $L^2,\text{unif}$ I think, but I do not recall details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [locally $L^2$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function), denoted by $L^2_{loc}$.

These are functions $f$ such that for every compact set $K$, $f \mathbb{1}_K \in L^2$.

Comment: He did require a uniform bound on the integrals over unit intervals, so that's not quite it, I think.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - true. Might be a starting point though.

Comment: no, that is indeed not what I was looking for, but thank you anyway.